# Creating SQL Job Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-job

I use SQL Server 2008 and .NET 3.5 Framework.

In my program, the stored procedures on database are altered according to the user inputs.

The user can determine dates for his task.

So, I want to write the program in a way that SQL Job for altering stored procs is created by program.

How can I create the job programmatically?

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't want to do this using bind variables?

Comment: Are you trying to only update the stored procs? If so, why do you need the job to do it?

Comment: @tobias86 Do you know any better way? @pm_2 I don't know about bind variables, but searching now.

Comment: @Ahmet: You could try just sending an `ALTER PROCEDURE` script to SQL Server, instead of scripting and firing off a job (in which you would have to specify the modified SP anyway). Is this what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Ahmet - Maybe if you posted the query that you're trying to create...

Comment: The alter operation should not be performed by program. Because it is going to happen on certain dates. If you are suggesting to perform it by application, it means writing something like Windows Service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it programmatically in two ways:

1.
If you need just to alter a procedure:

```
// written from the head
...
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Smo = Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;

string strConnectionString = ".......";
string strAlterProcCommandText = "ALTER PROC dbo.blablabla (..) AS .......\r\nGO";

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
{
  conn.Open();
  var server = new Smo.Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
  var result = server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(strAlterProcCommandText);
  Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
}
```

2.
Or if you want to do this with SQL Job, you may have to use the example above, but instead of `strAlterProcCommandText = "ALTER PROC..."` execute a command that will add a SQL Job. Usually I generate a sqljob query in this way:

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. In "Object Explorer" window of some server I go to: *SQL Server Agent » Jobs » Mouse-right-click » New Job...*
3. Then create a simple job that will look like I want to be executed, give the name to the created job
4. Right click on added job and follow this way in the context menu: *Script Job as » CREATE To » New Query Editor Window*
5. Copy the generated script, make it parameterized as you need, and then put to `strAlterProcCommandText`.

Hope you got my idea.

Comment: Altering is going to take place on certain dates. For example, it is going to add some code into proc today and remove the code next month. But all these dates are given by the user who only knows the UI of application. So, the job needs to be created by application or a windows service is essential?

Comment: hm, I guess this should be dependent from your needs. anyway, I'm sure there are a lot of different ways to make this work. For example, you can try Job class from SMO namespace to manipulate the jobs from C#. Take a look at this manual: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.job.aspx